# Yii Csqldataprovider pagination

Tags: yii, frameworks

Why my dataprovider is not displaying pagination?

```
$dataProvider=new CSqlDataProvider($sql,array('keyField' =>'inmueble_id','pagination'=>array('pageSize'=>1)));
```

I dont see the problem T_T

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the `totalItemCount` property with a count of the data you are fetching from query.

Ex:

```
$count=Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YOUr_TABLE')->queryScalar();
```

and pass count as

```
$dataProvider=new CSqlDataProvider(
                    $sql,
                    array(
                           'totalItemCount'=>$count,
                           'keyField' =>'inmueble_id',
                           'pagination'=>array('pageSize'=>1)
                          )
                    );
```